# Изменение регистра букв после определенного символа

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения, строки

Необходимо написать программу проверяющею есть ли в строке символ нижнего подчеркивания, если он есть проверить следующий за ним символ и узнать в каком он регистре. Если следующий символ за символом нижнего подчеркивания в верхнем регистре, то поменять его на символ нижнего регистра. Например есть строка `myNew_Nar` если символ `N` в верхнем регистре, то заменить его на символ в нижнем регистре и вывести измененную строку `myNew_nar`.
У меня получилось изменить только сам символ. А как вывести измененную строку? Возможно использовать регулярные выражения?

```
        String string = "hello_World_Hi";
        String s = "_";
        int length = string.length();
        char c = ' ';

        if (string.contains(s))
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
            {
                if (string.charAt(i) == '_')
                {
                    if (true)
                    {
                        c = string.charAt(i+1);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        if (Character.isUpperCase(c))
        {
            c = Character.toLowerCase(c);
        }
        System.out.println(c);
```

Comment: По-моему, ответ внизу верный. Примите, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(_[A-Z])");
Matcher m = p.matcher("myNew_VarX_VarY_varZ");
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
while ( m.find() ) {
    m.appendReplacement(sb, m.group(1).toLowerCase());
}
m.appendTail(sb);
System.out.println(sb.toString());
// myNew_varX_varY_varZ
```

Comment: Спасибо, помогли разобраться! @enzo